# Using Facebook php in codeigniter adds PHPSESSID to URLs?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I started using facebook php sdk with codeigniter but since then the urls on my website all have a 'PHPSESSID' added to the end.

I created a config file containing the app id and secret and used the following code to load the library.

```
$this->load->library('facebook');
```

Does anybody know of a workaround to this problem??

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @roopunk - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7643454/206613

Comment: a foolproof solution is what i meant :) plus the PHPSESSID is not there in my url but rather present as a cookie. dont wanna fiddle with the fb library actually. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing php.ini setting I went ahead and replaced the `$_SESSION` usages in `facebook.php` with Codeigniter sessions `$this->session->set_userdata()`. Works for me till now. Not very foolproof I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook script uses PHP native sessions. You can change this in your php.ini file:

```
# set
session.use_cookies = 1
# to
session.use_cookies = 0
```

http://www.webune.com/forums/disable-phpsessid-phpini.html

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out:

```
php.ini
session.use_trans_sid = 0
```

This will hide (make intransparent / invisible) all the PHPSESSID from your URLs.